# Launch node based on parameters from parameter server

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, is it possible to achieve conditional launching of nodes based on parameters (not arguments!) on roslaunch XML files?

A workaround I think of might be a dummy Python node that would eventually launch the given node after evaluating parameters, but being able to do so in the launch file directly would be great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215764/launch-node-based-on-parameters-from-parameter-server/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will probably never be supported in ROS 1. There was a series of pull requests that added the support, but it was not merged: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/2097 .

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2022-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0